# Show placeholder as a value in tablesorter with Selectize.js dropdown

Tags: tablesorter, selectize.js

This are my options of tablesorter:

```
        .tablesorter({
            theme: 'altair',
            headerTemplate: '{content} {icon}',
            widgets: ['zebra', 'filter'],
            widgetOptions: {
                filter_reset : 'button.ts_cf_reset',
                filter_cssFilter: [,'', 'ts_cf_datepicker_1','ts_cf_datepicker_2', 'ts_cf_select_single']
            }
        })
```

And the table is:

```
<table ref="listaElementos" className="uk-table uk-table-hover uk-table-align-vertical uk-table-nowrap tablesorter tablesorter-altair" id="ts_custom_filters">{/* id="ts_custom_filters ts_pager_filter" */}
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th className="uk-text-center filter-false remove">ID</th>
    <th className="uk-text-center" data-placeholder="Buscar empresa">Suministrador</th> 
    <th className="uk-text-center" data-placeholder="Seleccione rango">Fecha de contrato</th>
    <th className="uk-text-center" data-placeholder="Seleccione rango">Vencimiento de contrato</th>
    <th className="uk-text-center filter-select" data-placeholder="Seleccione Vigencia">Vigencia</th>
    <th className="uk-text-center filter-false remove">Acciones</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {contratos}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What I need is to show the placeholder "Seleccione Vigencia" as a actual option of a dropdown list (select) made it with selectize.js. I can see the placeholder when I load the table, but I lost the option when I open the dropdown.

Comment: I found the problem here too: https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/issues/163

Comment: Finally I solved the situation using this: http://jsfiddle.net/Unspecified/qrqJv/1/

Comment: Also, `className` is not the correct attribute. Use `class`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, forgot to mention that I'm using React.js with JSX compiler, and there is className.